# Analogues for, e.g., FTA and Rational Root Theorem for polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ ($\mathbb{Q}_p[X]$)?

Tags: polynomials, p-adic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, algebraic-numbers

For example, are there known bounds on the roots w/r to the $p$-adic metric?  Ways to determine how many roots are in $\mathbb{Q}$, or in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ itself as opposed to an algebraic extension?

Specifically, I am considering the following problem: given the *Collatz polynomial* polynomial $P_N$ whose constant term is $N$, whose leading coefficient is presumed to be 1, and such that $a_{k+1}$ is the Collatz iterate of $a_k$ if $a_k\neq 1$, what do the roots of $P_N$ look like?  Using Newton polygons I have managed to prove that every odd $N$ other than powers of $3$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some odd $p\neq 3$ dividing $N$ and that this root has valuation $m$ where $p^m\mid\mid N$, but am not sure what else to do with this information.

Possibly relevant is that these polynomials are linear combinations in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of products of cyclotomic polynomials; if some $\Phi_d$ appears in every product then the polynomial is reducible, but the converse is not true (e.g., $P_5(-1) = 0$).  I know that the $n^{th}$ root of unity $\omega_n$ is in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $n\mid p-1$.

Comment: I don't understand what is your polynomial and what you want to do with it.

Comment: The replacement of the rational root theorem is Hensel lemma: we can assume that $f\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is monic and separable. There is some $N=N_f$ such that if $v_p(f(a))\ge N$ then the sequence $a_N=a, a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}$ converges to a root of $f$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p$.